# Looking for discrete mathematics book

Tags: discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book I read some time ago and I forgot the title/authors.
It is a large book about 600 pages and was introductory to discrete mathematics. The first chapter was about falling/rising factorials and closed form for solving linear recursions.
Could someone direct me to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it!!!!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics
placeholder text